# Js function is not recognize in github page

Tags: javascript, function, github, github-pages, referenceerror

I have uploaded my local project to github and turned it into github page.

All the functions are working properly in my localhost but, when I open the app via [github page](https://htet-wai-yan.github.io/Frontend-Mentor-Challenges/) ([this is repo for you to see code](https://github.com/Htet-Wai-Yan/Frontend-Mentor-Challenges/tree/tip-calculator)), it shows the error on console that the function **calculateAmount()** is not defined. See the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQKE1.png)

I have tried pushing the code to github again a few time to make sure it is not commit error. But, the error is still the same.

I have double checked the function name and it is the same.

I have no idea what is happening.

Please help.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: Also look at **all** the error messages. It doesn't matter if you get the name of the function correct when your attempt to load the JS file is a `404 Not Found` error!

Comment: Your script URL should start with "public", not "/public"

Comment: Typo: Your URL is wrong. You didn't account for Github Pages projects being deployed to `/projectname` not to `/`.

Comment: @pointy and All. Thanks for the help. I am sorry I didn't check the js file path. Now it works